# TYPO3: get database records into plugin or custom CE?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase

I created an extension with a database table called "Cars". Now I would like the backend user to be able to select a certain car from the database in order to display it in the frontend.

Is it possible for example to create a custom content element or a plugin with the list of cars ?
What would be the best solution Custom CE or plugin ? How do I actually retrieve the database records ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a plugin with a FlexForm for them. In the FlexForm use a block like this:

```
<settings.selectedCars>
    <TCEforms>
        <label>LLL:EXT:yourextension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:flexforms_select_cars</label>
        <config>
            <type>group</type>
            <internal_type>db</internal_type>
            <allowed>tx_ yourextension_domain_model_car</allowed>
            <size>1</size>
            <maxitems>999</maxitems>
            <minitems>1</minitems>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</settings.selectedCars>
```